# Convert string output(bash script)

Tags: bash

How do I convert my output `vendor_id : GenuineIntel` to `vendor_id = GenuineIntel` using the cut command?

```
#!/bin/bash

VENDORID=`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'vendor_id'|cut -d`=`-f 5`
vendor_id: GenuineIntel
echo $VENDORID
```

Comment: Avoid backquotes (used for sub-commands), do not use them as single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tr`anslate:

```
vendorid=$(grep 'vender_id' /proc/cpuinfo | tr ':' '=')
printf "%s\n" "$vendorid"
```

I changed backticks to `$(..)` since they are easier to nest. Also remember to double quote your variable expansions `$vendorid` -> `"$vendorid"` or it will undergo [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting).

`tr` will in this case change all colons to equal signs, eg:

```
% echo "a:b:c" | tr ':' '='
a=b=c
```

Comment: @user3613649 I'm happy I could help :-)

Comment: I also want to run a script  for the utility from my CPU

Comment: @user3613649 Hopefully now you know how to progress? :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
VENDORID=$(sed -n '/vendor_id/{s/:/=/p;q}' /proc/cpuinfo)
```

Comment: This is a good answer, care you elaborate what `{s/:/=/p;q}` does - might not be obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Translate the character `:`into `=` with

```
 tr ':' '=' < /proc/cpuinfo
```

Assign to a variable with

```
vendorid=$(tr ':' '=' < /proc/cpuinfo)
```